# Godot Texture Not The Same As SubViewport

Tags: textures, viewport, godot

I am making a mirror, but there's a problem. The color is far different in the texture than in the subviewport I used in the texture.
[image]
On the bottom in Refl Tx, is what the subviewport looks like.
But at the top is what it looks like as a texture.
I have messed around with many settings but couldn't find a solution.
This is the shader code:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

uniform sampler2D refl_tx;
void fragment(){
    ALBEDO = texture(refl_tx, vec2(1.0 - SCREEN_UV.x, SCREEN_UV.y)).rgb;
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but here a couple things I would try: 1. Setting a `WorldEnvironment` in the `SubViewport`. 2. Changing `transparent_bg` to `true` and using the alpha channel in the shader to change the color (e.g. scale `rgb` by `a`).

Comment: @Theraot how would I go about doing your second solution? The scaling the rgb by a part that is.

Comment: You read the `texture` to a `vec4`: `vec4 txc = texture(refl_tx, vec2(1.0 - SCREEN_UV.x, SCREEN_UV.y));`, And for `ALBEDO` scale `txc.rgb` by `txc.a`, so `ALBEDO = txc.rgb * txc.a;`.

Comment: @Theraot sadly I get an error when trying to assign the texture to a vec4

Answer (score 2):

Add a `source_color` hint after your texture declaration.

```
uniform sampler2D refl_tx : source color;
```

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/shading_language.html#uniforms